# getOne(id) doesn't return null when object not found

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use getOne to get data from DB. When entity is not found, I can not check it with

```
obj = repository.getOne(id);//exception
if(obj == null){
...
}
```

I want to check if entity has been found or not, but I get an exception.

Comment: what is `// error`? If you *do* get an error. please post it in your quesiton

Comment: If you mean getOne in JPA Spring Data, it returns javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException if no entity exists for the given id. See the documentation.

Comment: @Max, I know, I want to check it found or not entity by if or anything.

Comment: You can 't do that using this method

Comment: @Max, you mean getOne(id) can not check found or not ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood you correctly. But if you want to see if an object to a given id exists you can just catch the `EntityNotFoundException`:

```
public boolean exists(int id){
    try{
        repository.getOne(id); // will throw if not exists
        return true;           // entity does exist
    } catch(EntityNotFoundException e){
        return false;          // entity doesn't exist
    }
}
```

But this is surely not the way to go. As there probably already exist such methods on the `repository`